# Call to undefined function result() in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

please help me, i've problem for get a value of database
in one page i called result() like code below :

```html
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Your Bird </a>
  <ul>
    <?php foreach ($burung->result() as $burung) {
      echo "<li><a href=\"panels.html\">$burung->burung</a></li>";
    }?>
  </ul>
</li>
```

and next code :

```html
<div class="row">
  <?php foreach ($burung.result() as $burung) {
      echo "
      <div class=\"col-md-3\">
        <div class=\"panel panel-default\">
          <div class=\"panel-body bk-primary text-light\">
            <div class=\"stat-panel text-center\">
              <div class=\"stat-panel-number h1 \">24</div>
              <div class=\"stat-panel-title text-uppercase\">$burung->burung</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a href=\"#\" class=\"block-anchor panel-footer\">Full Detail <i class=\"fa fa-arrow-right\"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>";
}?>
</div>
```

but the when i run this page doesn't work with message : 
Call to undefined function result()

Comment: `print_r($burung)` and post the data

Comment: $query->result() it's a query result object, you are using it wrong way? see https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
<?php foreach ($burung.result() as $burung) {
```

to this

```
<?php foreach ($burung->result_array() as $row) {
```

and inside code `$row['burung']`

---

> **Use/Change `result_array()` instead of `result()`. Read this [Result Arrays in Codeigniter.com](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#result-arrays)**

Comment: Alhamdulillah, thank for answer my question :)
problem has fixed

Comment: @AdemNatural Happy to help :)